# Octal to Decimal Conversion ( DEBUGGING)

Tags: c++, debugging

So the code is meant to convert a decimal number to octal, and i have overloaded the operator<< to give my output

However The conversion never happens and i get a wierd output

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
class OCTAL
{
    int octnum;
    public: int dec_oct(int);
            int oct_dec(int);
            OCTAL(int x)
            {

                octnum=dec_oct(x);
            }
            int operator+(int k)
            {
                return (oct_dec(octnum)+k);
            }
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,OCTAL);
};
int OCTAL::dec_oct(int x)
{

    int i=0,sum=0;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        sum+=((x%8))+(pow(10,i));
        x=x/8;
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int OCTAL::oct_dec(int x)
{

    int i=0,sum=0;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        sum+=(x%10)+pow(8,i);
        x=x/10;
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ps,OCTAL obj)
{
    cout<<obj.octnum<<endl;
    return ps;
}

int main()
{

    int x,k;
    cout<<"Enter decimal N\n";
    cin>>x;
    OCTAL n(x);
    cout<<"Octal + object ="<<n<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter base 10 No to be added\n";
    cin>>k;
    int y=(n+k);
    cout<<"Sum = "<<y<<endl;
}

    #include<math.h>
    using namespace std;
    class OCTAL
    {
        int octnum;
        public: int dec_oct(int);
                int oct_dec(int);
                OCTAL(int x)
                {

                    octnum=dec_oct(x);
                }
                int operator+(int k)
                {
                    return (oct_dec(octnum)+k);
                }
                friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,OCTAL);
    };
    int OCTAL::dec_oct(int x)
    {

        int i=0,sum=0;
        while(x!=0)
        {
            sum+=((x%8))+(pow(10,i));
            x=x/8;
            i++;
        }

    }

    int OCTAL::oct_dec(int x)
    {

        int i=0,sum=0;
        while(x!=0)
        {
            sum+=(x%10)+pow(8,i);
            x=x/10;
            i++;
        }
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& ps,OCTAL obj)
    {
        cout<<obj.octnum<<endl;
        return ps;
    }

    int main()
    {

        int x,k;
        cout<<"Enter decimal No\n";
        cin>>x;
        OCTAL n(x);
        cout<<"Octal + object ="<<n<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter base 10 No to be added\n";
        cin>>k;
        int y=(n+k);
        cout<<"Sum = "<<y<<endl;
    }
```

Output
Enter decimal Number to be converted
10
Octal + object =14

Enter base 10 No to be added
15
Sum = 29

Comment: 1st your functions don't return a value, you should have received a compiler warning about that. 2nd what would you expect as output? Integer numbers are integer numbers. Octal, hex, binary and decimal are textual representations. You should check the [c++ standard I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) how to output or input numbers in these representations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Octal and decimal are **external** representations of integer values. Internally, a value is just a value; it is not octal, it is not decimal, and it is not red. Converting an octal **input** to an integer value means converting a **text** input into an internal value; converting a value to octal means producing a **text** string that represents the internal value. Same thing for decimal. So when your task is to convert octal to decimal you start with a text string and end with a text string, typically converting to an integer value as in intermediate representation. So octal --> integer --> decimal, implemented as text --> integer --> text.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum+=(x%10)+pow(8,i);
```

Imagine `x` is 9.   You get 9 % 10 = 9 + 8^0 = 9 + 1 = 10.

I'm guessing that's not what you want.  You probably want 11 -- really you should return the value as a string, though.

The problem is that you're handing 10 possible values at a time (0-9), when you can't actually deal with more than 8.   ideally you'd be bit shifting x by 3 bits each iteration, that way you can always represent the value you're dealing with.

`x & 7` will give you the value of the first 3 bits, then you can shift x by 3 `x>>3` to prepare the next 3 bits to be read.

Here's something to get you started:

```
int main() {
    int x = 44;
    while(x > 0) {
        auto v = x&7;
        cout<<v<<endl;
        x=x>>3;
    }
}
```

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/50qDr48F9oyd5t4z